# Changing visibility of element in constraint.Group

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I have spent an hour trying to figure out, who is changing one of my views visibility. It turned out to be constraint.Group.

Well, from the start:
I have, for example, **seven** views, **five** of them (under certain circumstances) should have visibility GONE. **One** of these **five** views have its own logic to be visible or not, but if all five are gone, it is gone. I thought it is a good idea to place five elements in a constraint.Group , apply logic for group, and then apply logic for one of them. **Error**: one of them will have the same visibility as other in a group, even if I change it after inflate.

What has to be done here to preserve two kind of logic? Not using constraint.Group at all? Remove one view from constraint.Group?

Comment: You have to make group of four views and other remain alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, definitely you will need to remove that one view from `android.support.constraint.Group` if you want that specific view's visibility logic to work correctly as otherwise whatever the visibility of the `android.support.constraint.Group` will be there; will also get applied to the visibility of that view and that's why you need to exclude it from the `android.support.constraint.Group` to avoid problems and thus get your desired outcome.